# Form is not submitting with submit() method in jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, sweetalert2

I have a delete form like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('incoming.destroy', $incoming->id) }}"
   method="POST" 
   id="incomingDeleteForm{{$incoming->id}}"
>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit" data-id="{{ $incoming->id }}" class="incomingInvoiceDeleteBtnID">
    </button>
</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.incomingInvoiceDeleteBtnID').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var incomingID = $(this).data('id');
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure ?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this !",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            console.log("FORM ID: ", $("#incomingDeleteForm"+incomingID));
            $( "#incomingDeleteForm" + incomingID ).submit();
        }
    })
});
```

Form ID is giving me this:

[image]

But same code for others are giving me this:

[image]

Comment: Are those two pieces of code related in any way? `.incomingInvoiceDeleteBtnID` doesn't seem to appear in that code as well as `#incomingDeleteForm"+incomingID`

Comment: Yeah. All are connected properly. I have checked. Edited my Code. Thanks

Comment: Use `$('.incomingDeleteForm{{$incoming->id}}').submit()  ` instead of `$('.incomingInvoiceDeleteBtnID').on('click')`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: _token is not defined

Comment: That is because you dont have @csrf in your form

Comment: @Silidrone There is `csrf_token()` though

Comment: @brombeer Yea thats true

Comment: does console.log("FORM ID: ", $("#incomingDeleteForm"+incomingID).length); give 1?

Comment: Giving 0.......

Comment: Hi , can you try like this `$(this).closest('form').submit();` ?

Comment: @AspileInc so $("#incomingDeleteForm"+incomingID) is not found. Is the var incomingID available there? (try to console.log it )

Comment: @GertB., Yes. It's available.